# Windows:unable to log events to security log and status codes is 0x0

Tags: windows, powershell, eventlog-source

I am newbie to windows administration.
Recently got an alert describing,

> "unable to log events to security log and status codes is 0x0"

So far I identified that the exception could be due to the following reasons,

- Log file size is running out of memory
- server memory is running out of memory

But when checked everything seems to be normal..

The alert has been repeated several times.
Couldn't find a solution.

More information:

OS:Windows server 2008 R2.
HDD : enough space is there.
Log File size : more than 30MB is available.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 0):

Check event log permissions of the account that is running the command and ensure it has write access.